# Ionic http post to external url

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, http-post, access-control

Im trying to send a post to a url with Ionic using angular, but i have the response:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

I know that the external service is working, because i tested it by ajax and everything works perfectly...

Below the code used in AngularJS (Ionic) and Ajax:

Ionic:

```
var loginServiceUrl = 'http://url.com.br'; //It is not the real one
var loginServiceData = {
    email: email@email.com.br
    senha: 1234
};
$http.post(loginServiceUrl, loginServiceData).
then(function (res){
    console.log(res);
});
```

Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url : 'http://url.com.br', //It is not the real one
    data : {email: 'email@email.com.br', senha: '1234'},
    success: function(result) {
        $('html').text(JSON.stringify(result));
    }
});
```

Does anyone know why I get the post via ajax on my localhost and not with the ionic, also localhost?

Comment: did you find the answer?

Comment: Yep. A chrome extension: "Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *", https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Check this out. It is well explained how to handle issues like yours --> http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/

Comment: i tried that, but my low knowledge of AngularJs made me not get to do what I wanted using the factory... =/ And using just the proxy int ionic.project dosent work

Answer (score 1):

Try to add headers in your POST request.

//example of DataToSend

```
   var DataToSend = {
                    userID: deviceID,
                    coordLat : pos.coords.latitude,
                    coordLon: pos.coords.longitude
   };

   $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://url.com.br',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'},
            data: DataToSend
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

CORS has nothing to do with your frontend.

Before sending the POST request, browser send a OPTIONS request to the server to check if call from your domain is allowed or not.

Since, you are getting  Status 404, that means your server is not handling the OPTIONS request

**1. Allow the OPTIONS request (same as POST)**

Now come to second part i.e " Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "

After allowing the OPTIONS request, now set the response header of OPTIONS request (Browser will check the response of OPTIONS request and then process the POST request only  if there is 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' present in the OPTIONS response.

**2. Set the response headers of OPTIONS request**

```
response().setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
response().setHeader("Allow", "*");
response().setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
response().setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Referer, User-Agent");
```

*Example..*
(In Java)

Router:

```
OPTIONS /*all                         
controllers.Application.preflight(all)
```

Controller Function:

```
public static Result preflight(String all) {
        response().setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response().setHeader("Allow", "*");
        response().setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
        response().setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Referer, User-Agent, Auth-Token");
        return ok();
    }
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

*Cheers*